# Перенос текста на новую строку

Tags: python, pdf

В результате этого кода на страницу pdf файла накладывается этот текст. Но абзаца нет. Как сделать чтобы с новой строки?

```
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', 'Arial.ttf'))
can.setFillColorRGB(0, 1, 1)
can.setFont("Arial", 8)
text = "Привет, сегодня дождь\nи скверно"
can.drawString(350, 100, text)
can.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

drawString не поддерживает переход на новую строку. Нужно использовать drawText

```
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
t = can.beginText()
t.textLines(wrapped_text)
can.drawText(t)
```

Где wrapped_text - это текст, который я считываю из txt файла. Там текст разбит на строки, как мне нужно.

Альтернативный вариант - записать текст в тройных апострофах ''' *Здесь текст в несколько строк* '''

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте `"\r\n"` ну и другой метод

```
import os 
name = 'bandham'+ os.linesep + 'manikanta' 
print(name)
```